# React Higher Order Component that detects dom events that takes functional components as arg

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a scenario where I want to create an HOC that detects mouse events (e.g. `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`) when they occur on the HOC's `WrappedComponent`, then pass the `WrappedComponent` a special prop (e.g. `componentIsHovered`). I got this working by using a `ref` callback to get the wrapped component instance, then adding event listeners to the wrapped instance in my HOC.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default (WrappedComponent) => {
 return class DetectHover extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this)
   this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this)
   this.bindListeners = this.bindListeners.bind(this)
   this.state = {componentIsHovered: false}
   this.wrappedComponent = null
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
   if (this.wrappedComponent) {
    this.wrappedComponent.removeEventListener('mouseenter', this.handleMouseEnter)
    this.wrappedComponent.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.handleMouseLeave)
   }
  }

  handleMouseEnter() {
   this.setState({componentIsHovered: true})
  }

  handleMouseLeave() {
   this.setState({componentIsHovered: false})
  }

  bindListeners(wrappedComponentInstance) {
   console.log('wrappedComponentInstance', wrappedComponentInstance)
   if (!wrappedComponentInstance) {
    return
   }
   this.wrappedComponent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(wrappedComponentInstance)
   this.wrappedComponent.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.handleMouseEnter)
   this.wrappedComponent.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.handleMouseLeave)
  }


  render() {
   const props = Object.assign({}, this.props, {ref: this.bindListeners})
   return (
     <WrappedComponent 
      componentIsHovered={this.state.componentIsHovered}
      {...props} 
     />
   )
  }
 }
}
```

The problem is that this only seems to work when `WrappedComponent` is a class component — with functional components the `ref` is always `null`. I would just as soon place the `WrappedComponent` inside `<div></div>` tags in my HOC and carry out the event detection on that div wrapper, but the problem is that even plain div tags will style the `WrappedComponent` as a block element, which doesn’t work in my use case where the HOC should work on inline elements, too. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the css selector and the specific styles you need to the Higher Order Component like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const Hoverable = (WrappedComponent, wrapperClass = '', hoveredStyle= 
    {}, unhoveredStyle={}) => {

    class HoverableComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                hovered: false,
            }
        }

        onMouseEnter = () => {
            this.setState({hovered: true});
        };

        onMouseLeave = () => {
            this.setState({hovered: false});
        };

        render() {
            return(
                <div
                     className={wrapperClass}
                     onMouseEnter= { this.onMouseEnter }
                     onMouseLeave= { this.onMouseLeave }
                >
                    <WrappedComponent
                        {...this.props}
                        hovered={this.state.hovered}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        }

    }

    return HoverableComponent;
};

export default Hoverable;
```

And use Fragment instead of div to wrap your component:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <h1>My content</h1>
            </Fragment>
        )
        }
```

And then wrap it like this

```
const HoverableSomeComponent = Hoverable(SomeComponent, 'css-selector');
```